# Automatic removal of expired tokens in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Is there a simple way in Laravel to automatically remove expired tokens from database? For example I have a table with tokens for password resets, which should be valid only for some time, but after they expire, they're not removed until someone manually deletes them.

Comment: You can run `php artisan auth:clear-resets` to flush expired reset tokens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the built in Authentication system that comes with running the command `php artisan make:auth`, you can run the command `php artisan auth:clear-resets` to clear any expired password reset tokens from the `password_resets` table. You can use the `Task Scheduler` in Laravel to run this command weekly and remove these tokens for you automatically.